# Additional methods in a class module implementing an interface in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, inheritance, interface

I write a VBA macro for Microsoft Excel 2010.

Some of the modules in my project would really cry out for subclasses, but I already understood that inheritance is not supported.

Knowing that, I went the hard way and implemented all the methods again in each module using an interface.

However, now I experience that a method that only occures in one of the modules (but not in the interface) throws an exception:

> Method or data member not found!

I am not entirely sure but I have the feeling that this is somehow related to the interface.

Therefore I'd like to know the following:

- When implementing an interface in a module in VBA, is it still possible to write additional public subs for this module?
- If it's not possible, what would be the correct pattern to append certain functionality to a module that implements an interface?

Comment: If you declare a variable as the interface class, you can only call methods/properties of that interface.

Comment: you mean static binding, right? However, I declared the variable as the "real class" not the interface class... Should it work then?

Comment: Yes it should. Unless you post the code, we can't tell you why it doesn't.

Comment: of course. But I guess nobody would like to read the whole code. When you tell me it should work, I will try to make a minimal example.

Comment: @Rory thank you for your comment! Knowing that it should work I found the source of the problem myself (and you were right, it was a problem with the variable declaration). As your comment the question comprehensively, I would like to accept it. Would you like to formulate it into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable as the interface class, you can only call methods/properties of that interface, regardless of any other methods/properties exposed by the actual object type itself.